# Getting the Error 'mssql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource' when Trying to Add Table Data

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use PHP to insert a username and password into my MSSQL table. I am unfamiliar with MSSQL, but it is for a client. I am getting the error `mssql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource in` when I try to run my PHP page on the website.

Here is my PHP page code:

```
<?php
$con=mssql_connect("gbs.com","Gser","Robs1!","GBMser");
var_dump($con);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL'); }
if ($con) {
    echo ("Connection is succeed");
} else {
    echo ("Connection is fail");
}

var_dump($con);
mssql_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES ('d', md5('d'))");

if (!mssql_query) {
    // The query has failed, print a nice error message
    // using mssql_get_last_message()
    die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

mssql_close($con);
?>
```

Here is what my PHP page displays when I run the code:

```
resource(1) of type (mssql link) Connection is succeedresource(1) of type (mssql link) 
Warning: mssql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource in D:\Hosting\4502990\html\insertadminaccount.php on line 14
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you, everyone.

Comment: **mysqli**_connect_errno()? Really?

Comment: I don't think that is what is causing the error. I took it out earlier, and I still got the same error. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: You're mixing up APIs here. You need `mssql_get_last_message()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php

Comment: Of course that's not causing the error. You don't know *what* is causing the error, since you aren't asking the engine.

Comment: I updated my code, I also put in what you told me to put in. I am still getting the same error, though.

Comment: The connection is succeeding, and I took out the `die()`. I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: You are using the wrong params to `mssql_connect()`. The 4th arg is not the database name. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: I think it is the database name I am getting wrong. I got the error `resource(1) of type (mssql link) Connection is succeedresource(1) of type (mssql link) ` when I inputted the code you suggested. That is all of the code I have in the page. I updated my page code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by using the code:

```
<?php
$Conn=mssql_connect('servername','username','password!');
mssql_select_db('dbname',$Conn);

if( mssql_select_db ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Gotta love the Q&A style. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the query like this

```
mssql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password)VALUES ('rob_dewar01', md5('KingDozer'))",$con);
```

first query then conection, hope it helps

Comment: @Kelsey Please read carefully, I sincerely hope you did not actually run this in your script....